# CarrierWave: `maybe it is not an image? Original Error: `mogrify -strip!`

Tags: carrierwave

Using Carrierwave `1.3.1` on Rails `5.1.6.2` app. 
When uploading a large image, getting a...

```
Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: `mogrify -strip! /var/folders/19/hzl_0_sx19xf5sz8q2zhxh7w563yd8/T/mini_magick20190507-46146-6n4v4m.jpg` failed with error: mogrify: unrecognized option `-strip!' @ error/mogrify.c/MogrifyImageCommand/6253.
```

in `carrierwave.rb`

```
def strip
    manipulate! do |img|
        img.strip!
        img = yield(img) if block_given?
        img
    end
end
```

Comment: I ran into the same error, finally I realized I was trying to upload an SVG.